procfs access control ubuntu 24
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24, there was a problem with access to procfs files
The program requires access to the systemd process maps file
mv 2572 0.0 0.2 20472 11520 ? Ss 00:22 0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
mv@mvcp:/proc/2572$ cat maps 
cat: maps: Permission denied

mv@mvcp:/proc/2572$ ls -l | grep maps
-r--r--r--  1 mv mv  0 Nov 16 00:23 maps

strace cat maps
openat(AT_FDCWD, "maps", O_RDONLY)  = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

Try
sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
sudo sysctl -w kernel.dmesg_restrict=0

Is it possible to disable protection regardless of the risks?

Although its never recommended to change these settings unless you know what you are doing - like for an assignment or a CTF.
These settings are controlled by
$ grep -inr dmesg_restrict /etc/sysctl.d/
...
/etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf:25:# kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0

$ grep -inr ptrace_scope /etc/sysctl.d/
/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf:22:kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1

which are applied at boot. You can edit these files to set what you need or create a new file in the same directory with a higher priority something like 99-custom.conf with
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
kernel.dmesg_restrict=0

and then to apply these without reboot
sudo sysctl --system

you can always check with
sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope
sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict

